# Adding an image before breadcrumbs on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

I am trying to set an image before woocommerce's breadcrumb. I tried everything but I can't find the correct file to mod. I can do it also with js, but the image has to come by wp backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', function() {
    echo '<img src="your-image.jpg">';
}, 18, 0 );
```

Read the source code for best documentation: [templates/archive-product.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/archive-product.php#L30)

Comment: Nothing to do unfortunatelly

Comment: Where you have added this code? Try it in `functions.php`

Comment: this was the problem